# What lead to the innovation of Complex Numbers (i), what key problems it solved?

Tags: complex-numbers

So, as I am suppose to teach my brother the concepts of Complex Numbers, the very first question that, I got was, what lead to the discovery of this concept, 
surely the Mathematicians faced a roadblock, which they removed using the Complex Numbers. So if anyone can throw some light on this subject, it would be great.

Regards,
Neil

Comment: Seems best suited to HSM.SE.

Comment: Any response to my answer, Neil?

Comment: Well Gerry, thank you for your response, it did help me. It will help me teach my brother Complex Numbers.

Comment: You have the option of "accepting" the answer, by clicking in the little check mark next to it. If you need something more for this question, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roadblock was solving certain 3rd degree equations, equations of the form $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$. Formulas for solving such equations were found in the 16th century, but in the case where the equation has three real solutions, the formulas always involved square roots of negative numbers. See "casus irreducibilis".